# How to print long listing for files in a remote server using pysftp in Python2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, pysftp

I have a script which connects to remote server using pysftp and does all basic functions such as put,get and listing files in remote server(basic operation between remote and local machine). The script doesn't show me the long listing of files in a folder in remote machine.But it prints me the long listing of files in the current path in local machine. I found it strange and hence have been trying out all possible solutions like cwd,cd,chdir etc. Please find the particular portion of the code and help me resolve the issue.

```
if (command == 'LIST'):
    print"Script will start listing files"
    try:

       s = pysftp.Connection('ip', username='user', password='pwd')
    except Exception, e:
       print e
       logfile.write("Unable to connect to FTP Server: Erro is-->" + "\n")
       sys.exit()
    try:
       s.cwd('remote_path')
       print(s.pwd)
    except Exception, e:
       print e
       logfile.write("Unable to perform cwd:"  +  "\n")
       sys.exit()
    try:
       print(s.pwd)
       print(subprocess.check_output(["ls"]))
    except Exception, e:
       print "Unable to perform listing of files in Remote Directory"
       s.close()
       sys.exit()
```

Thanks and regards,
Shreeram

Comment: `command = "ls -l "+remote_folder_path` as command will get the output for a specific folder.

Comment: @selten98 But I am already in that path with any of the commands (cd/chdir/cwd)

Comment: Did you verify that you are there? It is also less code to just call `ls -l PATH`, you can get rid of all the cd's, chdir's etc.

Comment: @selten98 Before this portion of the code , I have an option just to do the basic listing using listdir method and it works for me. So i expected 'ls -l' would also work for me the same way. In these two cases I do change my folder using cwd. You can refer to that too.

Comment: You use pysftp and commands. Are you sure commands also changed the folder?

Comment: @selten98 -Ok, I will check with basic commands as well. Will update soon. Thanks !!

Comment: try:
           print('remote_path')
           my_command="ls -l " + remote_path
           values=commands.getstatusoutput(my_command)
           for i in values:
                 print i

Comment: Tried with the above codes, but it throws an error saying no such file or directory

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve the desired results?

Comment: Maybe add the starting directory in front of it as well?

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on "subprocess" methods

Comment: No, sorry. I don't know these modules well enough.